# Coldfusion query weird characters

Tags: sql, coldfusion

**Problem**

My (windows) server is showing an odd error when I use a query. However locally the query works just fine. The server adds Â everywhere in the query.

**The Error**

> Error Executing Database Query.
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '.product
>   =Ã‚Â ao_products.id where ao_ranks.target = '1' order by
>   ao_ranks.rank as' at line 1
>
> ```
> <cfset start = (page*perpage)-perpage>
>   <cfquery name="get">
>     select category,ao_products.id,model,name,rank,rating
> ```
>
> from ao_ranks inner join  ao_products
>   onÃ‚Â ao_ranks.product =Ã‚Â
>   ao_products.id where ao_ranks.target =
>   '#target#' order by ao_ranks.rank asc
>   limit #start#,#perpage#
>
> VENDORERRORCODE     1064
>
> SQLSTATE    42000
>
> SQL      select
>   category,ao_products.id,model,name,rank,rating
>   from ao_ranks inner join ao_products
>   onÂ ao_ranks.product =Â ao_products.id
>   where ao_ranks.target = '1' order by
>   ao_ranks.rank asc limit 0,16

**The Code (utf-8 encoded file)**

```
<cfelse>
<cfset start = (page*perpage)-perpage>
  <cfquery name="get">
    select category,ao_products.id,model,name,rank,rating from ao_ranks inner join ao_products on ao_ranks.product = ao_products.id where ao_ranks.target = '#target#' order by ao_ranks.rank asc  limit #start#,#perpage#
  </cfquery>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Linux Server? Windows Server? What file encoding?

Comment: Windows Server, UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Please have a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127711/coldfusion-xls-export-and-character-encoding

Comment: While you're in there, you need to wrap #target# with CFQUERYPARAM and wrap #start# and #perpage# with val() to avoid SQL Injection.

Comment: @da_didi Thats not the issue, this has nothing to do with writing to the browser or a file.

Comment: Have you tried using alias names for the joins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by capitalizing "on" in the query. I have no clue how this helped. But it did.